# LinkedList not working, getting errors

Tags: c#, linked-list

Im trying to make a linkedlist inside a dictionary, but Im getting the following two errors:

> error1: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList.AddFirst(System.Co‌​llections.Generic.LinkedListNode)' has some invalid argument
>
> error2: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode' ,

The code where the error is showing is[UPDATED]:

```
this.albumslist.AddFirst( album );
```

The relevant portion of the Artist class is[UPDATED]:

```
class Artist
{
    private string artistname;
    private string members;
    private string albums;
    private LinkedList<Albums> albumslist;

    public Artist(string artistname, string members, string album)
    {
        this.artistname = artistname;
        this.members = members;
        this.albumslist = new LinkedList<Albums>();
        this.albumslist.AddFirst( album );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all. The class `Artist` has only one constructor having parameters

```
string, string, LinkedList<Albums>
```

And you are trying to invoke this constructor with parameters:

```
txtArtistName.Text, txtMembers.Text,txtAlbum.Text
```

i.e.,

```
string, string, string
```

**EDIT**

**error1:**

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<ArtistsLibrary.Albums>.AddFirst(System.Co‌​llections.Generic.LinkedListNode<ArtistsLibrary.Albums>)' has some invalid argument--
```

Reason: You are passing a string value to `AddFirst` since it receives `LinkedListNode<ArtistsLibrary.Albums` as argument.

**error2:**

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode<ArtistsLibrary.Albums>'
```

Reason: It says, unable to convert the string to the type of `LinkedListNode<ArtistsLibrary.Albums>` since it expects that type (as mentioned in first reason).

Comment: thanks, I realised that now, but unfortunely getting still errors. please see my comment on the answer below.

Comment: @user3494713: Can you edit the question and show the code like you did first? Because Craig W. edited the question and removed those parts, no offense Craig. :-)

Comment: Thanks you, just one last thing, how should I implement it to get it working?

Comment: @user3494713: I need to see more of your code. Especially `AddFirst` function and where you create an object of the class.

Comment: @user3494713: You can pass the `ArtistsLibrary.Albums` instead of `txtalbum.text`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand why you're confused. The constructor for Artist takes a LinkedList as the third argument.

```
public Artist(string artistname, string members, LinkedList<Albums> albumslist)
```

In your code you're giving it a string as the third argument.

```
new Artist(txtArtistName.Text, txtMembers.Text,txtAlbum.Text)
```

You need to feed it a LinkedList, change the constructor of Artist to take a string, or add an additional constructor that takes a string.

```
public Artist( string artistName, string members, string album )
{
    this.artistname = artistname;
    this.members = members;
    this.albumslist = new LinkedList<Albums>();
    this.albumslist.AddFirst( new Album() { Name = album } );
}
```

I'm a little baffled as to why a LinkedList necessary rather than a simple List, but I'm assuming you've got a good reason for it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Craig W. Now im getting two more errors for: this.albumslist.AddFirst(album);  -- error1: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<ArtistsLibrary.Albums>.AddFirst(System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode<ArtistsLibrary.Albums>)' has some invalid argument-- error2: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode<ArtistsLibrary.Albums>' , any solution for these?

Comment: I updated the answer. AddFirst needs an instance of the type (Album in this case). I don't know what that class looks like so I guessed at the name of the property. Honestly though, it would be nice to see you put in some effort instead of just, "Oops, I got an error, I guess I'll just post to Stackoverflow and let someone else do my job for me." I'm always willing to help someone when they show some initiative.